# iOS Google Sign In not displaying above modally-presented view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I've been following the [directions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift) to get Google Sign On working on my iPhone app. I'm using XCode 11.5. My iOS target is iOS 12.1.

When you click the google Sign In button you've placed on a view controller, a little alert window is supposed to pop up and ask if you want to proceed to sign in with Google.

The problem is that this doesn't happen with my Google Sign In button on a view controller that I've presented modally. Instead, nothing happens when I click the button. I can't see any alert asking me do I want to Sign In with Google. My modal presentation code looks like this:

```
        print("Not logged in found.")
        if(loginVC == nil) {
            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            loginVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginViewController
            loginVC!.sessionTracker = sessionTracker! // some coredata stuff I use
            loginVC!.loginReceptionDelegate = logsVC! // view controller underneath this one
            loginVC!.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            self.navC!.present(self.loginVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

If I put a Google Sign In button on the view controller underneath the modally-presented one, then I see the alert when I click the Sign In button.

Why doesn't it work with the modally-presented view controller?

I've verified that I can see alerts created with `UIAlertController` above my modally-presented view controller, so I don't think the Google pod code is even attempting to proceed with the sign in flow for the user (my top view isn't obstructing the alert I created on my own).

This used to work. I had this exact same project working with version 4.x of Google's sign in framework about a year ago, but I bought a new mac laptop and when I cloned my project to the new computer, I encountered this issue. I've upgraded to version 5.x of their sign in pod but this hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: Which is the `presentingViewController` for Google sign in? Is it the modally presented one or the one underneath?

Comment: @Jithin, the modally-presented one is. loginVC in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flagged my question as a duplicate because I finally found the answer elsewhere here on stack overflow.

Anyway, the problem was that my modally-presented view had a tap gesture recognizer that was interfering with clicks on the Google button.

```
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Fixed it.